# Python execution with PHP on ubuntu works in shell, not in PHP

Tags: python, php, shell-exec

I am trying to create a python script that send a poll + message througout a messaging app, but my script doesn't seems to work.

First of all take into account that this command works from the SSH shell of the server:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/bitnami/stack/wordpress/polls-push.py
```

And correctly send my message to the service. (classic command line execution).

But once I call it with PHP, it does not work anymore:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd( '/usr/bin/python /home/bitnami/stack/wordpress/polls-push.py' );
echo '['.shell_exec( $cmd ).']';
```

I tried as well with and without `escapeshellcmd` and with both `shell_exec` and `exec` but nothing is working as expected. Same with absolute or relative path.

Here are my file rights:

```
$ ls -l polls-push.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bitnami bitnami 3749 Mar 28 15:35 polls-push.py
```

And my `polls-push.py` file starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
```

With error message:

```
echo '<div>exec + escape + err message</div>';
$cmd = escapeshellcmd( '/usr/bin/python /home/bitnami/stack/wordpress/polls-push.py 2>&1' );
echo '['.shell_exec( $cmd ).']';
```

Displays: `[]`

---

**Edit:** To get the error:

```
$arg = escapeshellarg( '/home/bitnami/stack/wordpress/polls-push.py' );
$exit = '2>&1';
$cmd = '/usr/bin/python '.$arg.' '.$exit;
echo shell_exec( $cmd );
```

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command so you capture the error messages.

Comment: @Barmar just tested, (added to question) but no error is thrown. (as expected, indeed, when executing normally, there is no error as well

Comment: Don't use `escapeshellcmd()` with this, since it escapes the redirection.

Comment: In general, I find it better to use `escapeshellarg()` on in dividual arguments, rather than `escapeshellcmd()`, because the latter doesn't know which parts are arguments versus shell syntax.

Comment: `escapeshellarg` is currently adding a slash before the &, so that may throw it off as well.

Comment: @Barmar do you mean something like this?

`$arg = escapeshellarg( '/home/bitnami/stack/wordpress/polls-push.py' );
$exit = escapeshellarg( '2>&1' );
$cmd = escapeshellcmd( '/usr/bin/python '.$arg.' '.$exit );`

This gives me the same result.

Comment: No, `$cmd = "/usr/bin/python $arg 2>&1";`. Don't use `escapeshellcmd()` at all.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Barmar, yes indeed no `escapeshellcmd` is not needed to get the error. I'll manage for the rest of the program, do you mind to add an answer here so I can flag this question "answered"?

Comment: I haven't answered the question, I just told you how to debug it yourself.